# Android Programming: Stay with CyanogenMod?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, cyanogenmod

My new Nexus One came pre-installed with CyanogenMod. It's great so far, but since I bought it for software development purposes (initially just *learning* how to program for Android), should I stay with it, or install the official Android OS (2.3)?

My main concern is compatibility issues with documented API, that is wasting time on debugging problems that shouldn't have been there in the first place.

Comment: I'd suggest you'd probably want ROMs of each configuration to test with. That way you can test for issues that may be specific to a certain OS revision (or, for that matter, Cyanogen Mod version). If you're only concerned about learning, you might want to stay with Cyanogen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just getting started?  It probably won't make a difference, so I would stay with Cyanogen mod.  It has the froyo api, and there are very few phones running gingerbread.  When gingerbread comes out for the nexus one, then you might want to consider switching, but until then, I would stay with it (unless your unhappy with it while using the phone).

Comment: what do you mean by "when gingerbread comes out for the nexus one"? Isn't it out already, as demonstrated by these eBay listings? http://goo.gl/QTtXj

Comment: @Android Eve, by gingerbread, I mean a port of gingerbread that is relatively stable.   From what I understand, the current nexus one ports of gingerbread are missing some major features and/or aren't really ready for 'prime time' yet.  That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Stay with 2.2 until you *need* to use something in SDK 9 to make the next killer app. I'm running a phone with Gingerbread, having come from a Nexus One with Cyanogen. Yes, it's cool, but I miss all the convenience of Cyanogen.

Comment: thanks. Wouldn't it be better to install 2.3 just for the performance improvement? Also, is there a comprehensive **list** of all Cyanogen conveniences? (I found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CyanogenMod but it's not a full list)

Comment: [Conveniences](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_vendor_cyanogen/blob/froyo/CHANGELOG.mkdn). Performance: no. On a Nexus One you'll get better performance with Cyanogen 6 than an early mod of Gingerbread.

Comment: thanks again (and +1's again :). What do you mean by "stay with 2.2"? Official 2.2 or Cyanogen 2.2?